# Windows new Azure VM missing endpoint setup options

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I created a VM with windows server 2012R2 with SQL Server 2014 on it and I can't seem to find where the endpoint settings are. I need to setup and endpoint to allow for remote connections with SQL Server Management Studio. I've noticedin the older "Classic" VM setup the endpoint settings show up, but in the newer "Virtual Machines" creation in Azure endpoints are not there. Here is a picture of the settings. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security groups for Resource Manager are created at the interface / Subnet level. If you select 'Network Interfaces' from the list above, you will be able to select the network security group.

You may need to create a new group via the `New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup` Powershell command

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find the default security group when I clicked on "Network Interfaces" and add a new security rule.